# Ajax RPC and jquery tabs system conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tabs, conflict

I'm trying to make a ajax RPC on page which contains tabs, i already try .noconflict() function, when a made it, the jquery code doesn't work. And when the tabs work, the ajax doesn't.
The code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tc div').hide();
    $('#tc div:first').show();
    $('#tabs ul li a').removeClass('current');
    $('#tabs ul li a:first').addClass('current');

    $('#tabs ul li a').click(function(){
      $('#tabs ul li a').removeClass('current');
      $('#tabs ul li a:first').removeClass('current');
      $(this).addClass('current');
      var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
      $('#tc div').hide();
      $(currentTab).show();
      return false;
    });
});

function changeContent(str) {
  if (str==""){
    document.getElementById("content_ops").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
      document.getElementById("content_ops").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  } 
  xmlhttp.open("GET","inc/get.php?id="+str, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

What's wrong with the code? Thanks

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: the $.noConflict relinquishes the $ from jQuery, and then straight after that you have a $(document).ready(). Replace all the $ after the noConflict with jQuery

Comment: OJay i already try it, but still don't work...